# Select Case inside Range loop

Tags: excel, vba, select, case

I have created a macro that flows down the rows in a worksheet to evaluate data in columns and change the row color and/or text color based on the found data.

```
Sub msFormatting()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row          'Find last populated cell in column A
    For r = 2 To lastRow                                    'Loop through all rows starting from row 2
        Select Case Cells(r, "A")
            Case "m"
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 204)
            Select Case Cells(r, "C")                       'Find value in column C
                    Case Is > Date - 1825                   'Age is under 5yrs
                    Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                   Case Is < Date - 7300                    'Age is over 20yrs
                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 124, 128)
                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Font.Color = RGB(250, 190, 0)
                End Select
            Case "s"
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 236, 255)
            Select Case Cells(r, "C")
                    Case Is > Date - 1825
                    Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                   Case Is < Date - 7300
                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Interior.Color = RGB(55, 145, 170)
                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Font.Color = RGB(250, 190, 0)
                End Select
            Case ""                                         'Clear formatting when blank
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "AC")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        End Select
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

On another worksheet I want to use a similar format however the data is only in one cell on the row but that sell varies in each row as some of the data is 'indented' by using the next column to show clarity.

I have become lost trying to add the search for the cell in the row, then using the case, evaluate the first portion of the cell text string to determine the change needed to the row color and/or text color based on the found data.

```
Sub SahanadFormatting()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'Find last populated row on worksheet
    For r = 4 To lastRow                                                                  'Loop through all rows starting from row 4
        With Rows(r)
            .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Select                'find & select cell with data
        End With

        Select Case ActiveCell.Address                                                    'Cell with data
            Case Mid(7, 1) = "m"                                                          'Verify 7th place is mare
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 204)   'Fill color

            Select Case ActiveCell.Address                                                'Find year foaled
                    Case Left(4, 1) > Year(Now) - 1825                                    'Age is under 5yrs
                    Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    Case Left(4, 1) > Year(Now) - 7300                                    'Age is over 20yrs
                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 124, 128)
                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Font.Color = RGB(250, 190, 0)
                End Select

            Case Mid(7, 1) = "s"                                                          'Verify 7th place is stallion
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 236, 255)

'            Select Case Cells(r, "C")
'                    Case Is > Date - 1825
'                    Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
'                   Case Is < Date - 7300
'                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Interior.Color = RGB(55, 145, 170)
'                       Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Font.Color = RGB(250, 190, 0)
'                End Select
            Case ""                                         'Clear formatting when blank
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "Z")).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        End Select
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Very simple, hacky solution that will work IF a) the evaluated data still is within a few columns(not spread to wide), b) the cells used for indents are empty. You could simply concatenate the values from the cells on the same row that hold the evaluated value. Then use select case on the combined string.

Comment: Also, be aware that your Cells and Range calls are implicit calls to ActiveSheet or the worksheet this code is written in. https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/